# Mongoid - Deletion module

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid3

I have a list of student_names in index page. If i delete a student it will destroy the entire document from the Mongo Database.

But if i delete it from the index page it should delete from the list but don't want to delete it from the Mongo Database. I don't want to destroy any data from my database!!!

`I know the other ways to achieve` it but i wanted to know in mongoid can we need to include an extra Mongoid module to support it. Is their any feature available in mongoid!!!

for ex:

```
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps
```

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. But do you want to delete something from your client view without that being sent to your server? Not seeing how this is a mongoid issue if that is the case. That is just JavaScript. Possibly re-phrase/re-think your question.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. Mongoid provides you with the simple CRUD functionality any other database would. For hiding data you need to set an attribute as `hidden` and then not show hidden records on your view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is

```
include Mongoid::Paranoia
```

but the problem its not gonna be supported for long time.  Check [mongoid docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/extras.html#paranoia)

So if you plan to upgrade to mongoid 4 don't depend on this.

Answer (score 0):

If planning to do this with upto mongoid 3, you can use **Mongoid::Paranoia** with. Paranoia uses **deleted_at** attribute for deleted documents to distinguish them from the rest and apply a scope on deleted_at: nil by default.

```
include Mongoid::Paranoia
document.delete   # Deleting it from index but keep it in DB
document.delete!  # Delete it from collection permanently
document.destroy  # Sets the deleted_at field, firing callbacks.
document.destroy! # Permanently deletes the document, firing callbacks.
document.restore  # Brings the "deleted" document back to life.
collection_class.deleted # To show all deleted documents (marked as deleted)
```

If you are planning to move along with mongoid 4, you can give a shot at https://github.com/simi/mongoid-paranoia , which also doing the same thing for mongoid 4.